# Ruby - set_trace_func on forked processes

Tags: ruby, ipc, trace

I'd like to achieve the following:

Build a Ruby command line utility that registers some set_trace_func events, then invokes whatever ruby-executable argument you pass to it (say `rspec`). The registered events then carry over to the command invoked.

Pseudo code of `myutility`:

```
set_trace_func() # Set some events here

exec(ARGV.join(' ')) # Execute argument passed
```

Then call as `myutility rspec`.

My objective here is to actually **register trace points on arbitrary commands** (as long as they are using ruby shims).

Things I have tried:

1. `exec` Does not work, for obvious reasons (it replaces the process entirely).
2. popen, system, backticks. These start an independent process.

I can use some form of IPC, but that assumes control over the command I am invoking with my utility. This is not the case; I'd like to accept arbitrary Ruby-executable arguments.

Is this possible? One thing I have not looked at closely is drb, but that too assumes some interference with outside arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject some code into ruby process by adding arguments to ruby interpreter, so your utility can be split in two parts - runner and payload. Payload is just another script, it registers for `set_trace_func` etc. upon require, and runner inject the former into target script like so:

```
exec('/usr/bin/env', 'ruby', '-r', payload_full_filename, *ARGV)
```

This will make ruby to `require` your payload into process first and then proceed with running target script itself (payload will run even if target script cannot compile)

Comment: Awesome. I was doing ruby -r from the command line; didn't know exec allowed this. This is the correct answer. One quick follow up question: how can I make this work with commands that themselves invoke ruby? Like rspec. As it stands now it through an error saying it can't find rspec, naturally.

Comment: as I remember - rspec does not invoke ruby by default, but can work over a drb, also you can run into `spring`-ed executables

Comment: as for 'not found' error - because running without shell you'll have to resolve script full path yourself (or by passing to `which` before/in runner)

Comment: you said "[rspec] can work over a drb", what do you mean by that? How can I make client (command I pass to my script) work over drb when I don't have access to the client code?

Comment: a meant that rspec can be (and in large project probably is) made to work with `spork` (https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) which accelerates tests startup by preloading stuff and forking, it works over drb, and may be a problem for your tool, because heavy-lifting is done in other process